# percentage not showning in center of circular progress bar?

Tags: android, android-layout

*my code is absolutely right but problem is that it does not show percentage in center of circular progress bar when press start button, but when i change the place of percentage instead of center  it starts showing percentage progress while pressing start button. please check the picture*

not showing percentage

[image: not showing percentage]

showing percentage

[image: showing percentage]

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:background="#0ef1e9"
        >
  <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_progressbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="280dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

   <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

   <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pb"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progressbar_states"
            android:layout_centerInParent="false"
             />

  </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/rl_progressbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl_progressbar"
        android:background="#76ee00">
       </Button>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Apps"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/rl_progressbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl_progressbar"
        android:background="#76ee00"
        ></Button>
 </RelativeLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try adding android:gravity="center" in your ProgressBar

Comment: gravity option does not work in relative layout.

Comment: Actually add android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center" to your TextView, not to ProgressBar as I said earlier. This should work.

Comment: sorry it did not solve.